# Three.js How update all materials?

Tags: three.js

I want to modify the fragment of the fog, but I ran into a problem, the materials do not apply the changes.

I modify the code i so

```
THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_pars_fragment" ] = [
    '...'
].join("\n");
```

Modification of the code occurs at the end after the whole scene is loaded.

I tried to do so

```
scene.traverse(function(object){
        if(object.material){
            object.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
})
```

But nothing has changed :(

Comment: Modifying `ShaderChunk` only modifies the text code of that chunk. When a material is created, the `ShaderChunk`s are assembled and concatenated (not referenced) into finalized shader code. This is why altering the code after-the-fact has no effect. Instead of modifying an existing material, consider creating your own named material (`THREE.MyPhongMaterial = ...`) which can use a custom fog chunk (`THREE.ShaderChunk[ "my_fog_fragment" ] = ...`).

Comment: Three should trigger a shader recompilation at a certain point. I don't know off the top of my head what does it. I thought `needsUpdate` would work. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11475

Comment: @TheJim01 I have different materials including for the skeleton, so I can not create my own shaders) I tried again to add a light source because I know the library does the reconstruction of the program. But something did not help, I will try further)

Comment: I don't understand your apprehension. You aren't restricted to one shader for everything. You can create as many shaders and materials as you want. Perhaps adding a simplified use-case (show us how you're applying materials to your objects) could help clarify your position.

Comment: I use standard materials, an example http://dt-byte.ru/f9c96cb3.png Fog is used on all materials, I just want to modify the fog, but the fog has only three parameters (color, far, near) for these parameters is not enough for me, I can not add uniforms to the fog either. I found a way, after modifying the fog, you just need to clear the scene and reload it)

Answer (score 2):

.needsUpdate cannot work, see https://discourse.threejs.org/t/change-shadow-params-dynamically/9165/9 TLDR as long as the material remains cached it won't be re-compiled.

```
function reset(gl, scene, camera) {
  scene.traverse((object) => {
    if (object.material) gl.properties.remove(object.material)        
  })
  gl.info.programs.length = 0
  gl.compile(scene, camera)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scene.traverse(object => {
    if(object.type === 'Mesh') object.material.needsUpdate = true;
});
```

works perfect in my case